# Compilation error when trying to compile a singleton in c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to study c++.
I wrote a file "Singleton.h" as follows:

```
class Singleton
{
private:
    static Singleton* m_this;
    Singleton();
public: 
    static Singleton* getInstance(){
        return m_this;
    }
    virtual ~Singleton();
};
```

my Singleton.cpp file:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Singleton.h"
Singleton::Singleton(){}
Singleton::~Singleton(){}
```

I call in my main method to get getInstance method as follows:

```
Singleton* s = NULL;
s = Singleton.getInstance();
```

But, I get compile error:

```
error C2275: 'Singleton' : illegal use of this type as an expression
```

Do you know why is that?

Comment: Since you tampering with the anti-pattern singleton: Why `virtual ~Singleton();` ???

Comment: You will also want to ensure that you have assigned a `new Singleton` to `m_this` before `getInstance()` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = Singleton::getInstance();
```

Not `.`, but `::`(scope resolution operator) for static methods.

Answer (score 0):

use scope resolution operator

```
 s = Singleton::getInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should call by using `Singleton::` like

```
Singleton* s = NULL;
s = Singleton::getInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope operator `::` instead of `.`
Also, you are going to get link error, you need to add

```
Singleton* Singleton::m_this;
```

to Singleton.cpp

But preferably, use a `namespace` instead